# Run Word mail merge for one line only

Tags: forms, vba, excel

First let me start by saying that I have no idea what I'm doing. Well, some idea, but mostly I'm just winging it. I've been working on an Excel macro to run a Word mail merge from Excel for a couple of weeks and I've pieced together different codes to encompass everything I need it to do. My problem is that it works the first time but it gets stuck each subsequent time if I do not reset the macro.

The sheet I made is designed so the macro can pull all of the information it needs from the sheet (code contains no hard coded locations). This is because a folder containing the Excel form, the letter templates and the finished letters will be sent to multiple users and will therefore be saved in a different location on each user's computer. The user enters details into the Excel form which will ultimately create a formatted disciplinary letter in a Word document to send out to the player being reviewed. There may need to be multiple infractions included in the letter so the Excel form provides that option, whereas a Word form would have a bunch of unnecessary empty fields. (I initially tried setting up the letter in Word as a form but I couldn't get all of the factors that I needed to work together) A Word form also doesn't have the ability to hide fields and can't support the dependent drop down lists or the amount of text in each drop down that I require. Anyway...

**The process:**

1. User opens the Excel file and enters information into a nicely laid out, user friendly form which contains dependent drop down lists, etc as well as buttons that hide and show fields (in case the user needs to include multiple infractions being reviewed).
2. When the user is finished entering their information, they click a command button to run the mail merge ("Create Disciplinary Letter").
3. The information they select in the form is linked to another worksheet (same workbook) called "Data Sheet" that contains the columns that the merge will pull from.
4. The workbook also contains a "Control Sheet" worksheet which provides the location of the files and folders that the macro is to pull from.

**The macro should:**

1. Open Word merge template (it chooses the correct template based on a choice that the user makes in the form)
2. Run the merge
3. Send merged product to a new document
4. Close the original merge template without saving changes
5. Save the new document with a specific file name (based on choices the user made in the original Excel form)
6. Save it to a "Final Documents" folder which is located in the original folder that I send out to the user(s).
7. The newly saved document/letter stays open for further editing (if necessary)
8. New doc contains a button that will save the finished letter as a .pdf (also to a specific location) but that macro is in Word so it is not part of my problem.

The Excel form would likely be closed and reopened before a user needs to use it again, and in that case, the macro would run fine. There is a good possibility though, that the user will see the finished letter in Word, realize that they forgot the include an infraction, go back to the open Excel form to add the infraction, and click the macro button again. If this happens, the macro will get stuck at macro process #4 onward (from list above). I don't know what is in the code (or missing) that is causing this but I've been fighting with it for days and I can't find anything out there that I can apply to my issue. Or maybe I have, but I'm unaware because I'm seriously just winging it.

```
Sub RunMerge()

Dim bCreatedWordInstance As Boolean
Dim wdapp As Word.Application
Dim wddoc As Word.Document
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsControl As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet

Dim strWorkbookName As String
Dim strTemplateFolder As String
Dim strTemplateName As String
Dim lngTemplateNameColumn As Long
Dim strFinalDocumentFolder As String
Dim strFinalDocumentName As String
Dim lngDocumentNameColumn As Long
Dim lngRecordKount As Long ' not used but retained for future use

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsControl = wb.Worksheets("Control Sheet")
wsControl.Activate
strTemplateFolder = wsControl.[Template_Folder].Value
strFinalDocumentFolder = wsControl.[Document_Folder].Value
Set wsData = wb.Worksheets(wsControl.[Data_Sheet].Value)
wsData.Activate
lngTemplateNameColumn = wsData.[Template_Name].Column
lngDocumentNameColumn = wsData.[Document_Name].Column
Set rng1 = wsData.Range("B1:B8")
strTemplateName = strTemplateFolder & "\" & wsData.Cells(2, lngTemplateNameColumn) & ".doc"
strFinalDocumentName = strFinalDocumentFolder & "\" & wsData.Cells(2, lngDocumentNameColumn)
strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name\

On Error Resume Next

' Create a Word Application instance
bCreatedWordInstance = False
Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.application")
If wdapp Is Nothing Then
Err.Clear

Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
bCreatedWordInstance = True
End If

If wdapp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Could not start Word"
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
End If

' Let Word trap the errors
On Error GoTo 0

' Set to True if you want to see the Word Doc flash past during construction
wdapp.Visible = True



' check that template exists
If Dir(strTemplateName) = "" Then
MsgBox strTemplateName & " not found"
End If

Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strTemplateName)
If wddoc Is Nothing Then Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strTemplateName)
wddoc.Activate

With wddoc
.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Data Sheet$`"

With wddoc.MailMerge  'With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
.SuppressBlankLines = True
.Execute Pause:=False
End With
End With

' Save new file
ActiveDocument.SaveAs strFinalDocumentName


' Close the New Mail Merged Document
If bCreatedWordInstance Then
wddoc.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set wddoc = Nothing


End If


0:
Set wdapp = Nothing
Set rng1 = Nothing
Set wsData = Nothing
Set wsControl = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

It gets stuck the second time around on:

```
' Save new file
ActiveDocument.SaveAs strFinalDocumentName
```

Comment: We'll need to see the macro

Comment: @b3tac0d3 Do i just edit my original post to add the macro?

Comment: That should do the trick. We can't debug it if we can't see it. Make sure you put it in code brackets so it's readable

Comment: I just had a thought. Maybe it gets stuck there because if the macro runs again for the same info, the file name and location are the same, so maybe it is not working because the file already exists...

Comment: does it throw any errors? does it highlight any lines in red or yellow? - also - does it work if you change the "savedocumentname" and run again without closing the worksheet?

Comment: btw - {on error resume next} would skip any errors and not allow you to debug properly. If you're getting errors, you should fix them, not overlook them. An error handler would work better here and could lead you to the problem.